# How to run custom manage.py in crontab + virtual env?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, cron

How to run in crontab

```
*/1 * * * * /home/user/Desktop/job/dp/ python manage.py statistics
```

with virtual env? I need to activate virtualenv first(Otherwise it does not work)

This is my virtual env:

```
source job/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDITED**:

Try something like this:

```
*/1 * * * * . /path-to-env/bin/activate && /home/user/Desktop/job/dp/manage.py statistics
```

This should be read as: activate the env and if that was successful, excute the manage.py script. Since manage.py is supposed to have a python shebang and the virtual env sets the correct python interpreter, this should work.

Apparently cron usually runs with `/bin/sh` which does not know the `source` command. So one option is to use a dot as a `source` replacement. Another to set `/bin/bash` in the cron file:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
*/1 * * * * source /path-to-env/bin/activate && /home/user/Desktop/job/dp/manage.py statistics
```

Read more about this issue at:
http://codeinthehole.com/writing/running-django-cronjobs-within-a-virtualenv/
The article doesn't mention that `source` can be replaced by a `.`, but i've just tried it and it worked for me. So you have several options to choose from now, the article even has others. ;)

Comment: */1 * * * * /Desktop source job/bin/activate && /home/user/Desktop/job/dp python manage.py statistics   not work

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please also make sure to use absolute paths or chain them with a `cd` command accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Use something like `~/envs/someenv/lib/python /path/to/your/script`

In your situation it will look like

`*/1 * * * * ~/envs/someenv/lib/python /home/user/Desktop/job/dp/manage.py statistics`